# Adding to an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON String that I have converted into an object with:

```
data=eval("(" + jsonString + ")");
```

I can access all the bits and display them with no issues.
The question is how do i add to the object.

For example:

```
data.car[0].name = "civic";<BR>
data.car[1].name = "s2000";
```

So, if I have an input box to add a new car, how do I add that to the car array.?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using your example above, something like:

```
data.car[0] = { name: "civic" };
data.car[1] = { name: "s2000" };
```

This will assign a new object to the array element, with one property 'name'. Alertnatively, for a bit more code re-use:

```
function car( name) {
    this.name = name
}
data.car[0] = new car("civic");
data.car[1] = new car("s2000");
```

Comment: It would mean though that the members of the array would have different constructors, that may be useful, OTH it could cause a problem.

Comment: You would destroy other properties from car

Comment: Depends on the usage, but yeah it could cause issues if using instanceof

Answer (score 1):

This will add a new car to the array:-

```
data.car.push({name: "Zafira"});
```

BTW, you want to be careful with using eval to parse JSON, it could lead you code open to an injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there are 2 ways to add a property to an object.

1. With direct

   ```
   data.car[0].name = 'jose';
   ```
2. Acessing just like a array:

   ```
   data.car[0]['name'] = 'jose';
   ```

So if you have one field to a name and one for the value you can create then just like:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="value" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    data.car[0][d("name").value] = d("value").value
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the syntax that you posted. Javascript lets you add properties to an object just by assignment. Since the JSON string is just parsed as a normal object, you can just specify a new property and assign the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuiming you have an input box you could attach a blur event (or whenever you want the car added)

```
function addCar(carname){
    data.car.push({name:carname})
}
```